# Using the pen tool for drawing a geometric pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool

I'm very new to illustrator and I'm trying to create a card for a baby birth.
One of the things which I would like to place on the card is a geometric image of a bear.

[image]

Now, I'm trying to draw this using the Pen tool drawing straight lines.
However, when I have multiple lines originating in the point, I see the following behaviour:

[image]

You'll see the lines are not beautifull.
How can I avoid this, and it the pen tool the correct item to draw this kind of images?

Please forgive a newcomer on Illustrator :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to check the round-joint option in the stroke panel with the desired path selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. And just to confirm, it the pen tool the right tool for this kind of task?

Comment: @Complexity That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the stroke panel.

There are some optios Cap and Corners.

In my opinion, the round one is the best option for your work.

Enabele the snap (ctrl  + U) to control the position of anchors.

See the image below:

[image]